# Is there a way to download APK of AAB file from Amazon's Developer Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apk, android-app-bundle

1. Upload a AAB file
2. Go to uploaded files page
3. Click the replace Bandle
4. Download > just can download the same AAB file.
5. May I have any way to download the APK from AAB file?
   Thank you very much

[image: [Download APK from Amazon's Developer Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWDqu.png)]